# iOS delegate is nil when trying to pass data back with Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I know this is a pretty common question but I've tried the various solutions offered here (that are not too old) and in numerous tutorials and I just can't seem to find out why it's still failing for me. Basically setting `sendingViewController.delegate` to self ends up being `nil` in sendingViewController. I understand this is very likely because the reference to the sendingViewController is being disposed of.  But here is why I'm asking this again.

First, almost every tutorial and every other StackOverflow post is wiring up the mainViewController and the sendingViewController differently. I'm trying to make this work through a Navigation Controller, what one would think is the most common pattern for this.

In the app I'm building (which is more complex than the sample I'm going to show), the mainViewController calls the Settings viewController through a right navbar button. Then the user can select items from a list, which opens a controller with a searchBar and a tableView of items to select from. I need that third view controller to return the selected item from the table view to the settings screen. I'm using storyboards as well. I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm not ready to do all this "programmatically". Any way in the sending view controller, my delegate which should have been set in the calling view controller is nil and I can't invoke the protocol function in the main view controller to pass the data back.

I did a tutorial directly (not using Nav controllers) and I got that to work, but the moment I deviate away, it starts failing. I then put together a streamlined project with two view controllers: `ViewController` and `SendingViewController`. ViewController was embedded in a navigation controller and a right bar button was added to go to the SendingViewController. The SendingViewController has a single UI Button that attempts to call the protocol function and dismiss the SendingViewController. I'm not using Seque's, just a simple buttons and protocol/delegate pattern as I can.

My question is what am I missing to actually set the SendingViewController.delegate correctly?

Here's some code:

```
//ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var showDataLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func fetchDataButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SendingViewController") as! SendingViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        print("fetching data")
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: SendingViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendData(value: String) {
        print("got Data \(value)")
        self.showDataLabel.text = value
    }


}
```

and

```
// SendingViewController.swift
import UIKit

protocol SendingViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendData(value: String)
}

class SendingViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SendingViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func sendDataButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("attempting to send data \(self)")
        print("to \(self.delegate)")
        self.delegate?.sendData(value: "Hello World")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Storyboard:
[image]
The ChildViewController does have a storyboard id name of "ChildViewController". All buttons and labels have their appropriate IBOutlet and IBAction's set up.

Help!

Comment: BTW: print("to \(self.delegate)") is printing "nil".

Comment: Dismissing the view controller will do the job try adding self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) instead of popping up inside sendData IBAction

Comment: One question , I want to know that you want to pass data with delegate or can I suggest some other solution like you can make a global variable and use it  for passing data anywhere.

Comment: Oh, global variables (as bad as they are) would super simplify my life. But I want to do this the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

i copy paste your code .. its working perfect .. i make just one change

instead of pop you need to use dismiss as you are presenting from your base viewController

```
 @IBAction func sendDataButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("attempting to send data \(self)")
        print("to \(self.delegate)")
        self.delegate?.sendData(value: "Hello World")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

here is the project link we.tl/t-NUxm9D26XN

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sending the project back. It's a partial solution. The problem blocking the delegate was a "Triggered Segue" action being set on the navbar button that went to the sendingViewController. As soon as I removed that action, delegation now works, but this has created a second problem.

The sendingViewController isn't part of the navigation bar any longer. So I can't use the buttons in the navigation bar.

In the actual app, I go:  Main->Settings->Locations. Breaking the Triggered Segue returns data but I no longer have a button to get to the Locations screen

Comment: I appreciate the insight, but it didn't solve the problem. While your FetchData button is in the navbar, your SendingViewController is not and you're not calling/returning data with regards to the way navbar's work. Back to more Googling.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working. In the receiving/parent view controller that needs the data:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let controller = segue.destination as! sendingViewController

    controller.cityDelegate = self
}
```

Then in the sending view controller in my tableView did select row function:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
    {

```
    let city = filtered[indexPath.row]

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.cityDelegate?.addCity(city)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I don't think I should be both popping the view controller and dismissing it, but it works. Also in the view controller I did this:

```
private var presentingController: UIViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    presentingController = presentingViewController
}

override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParent: parent)

    if parent == nil {
    }
}
```

I don't know if I really need this didMove() or not since it doesn't really do anything.

But some combination of all this got it working.

In my other app I'm not using a navigation bar controller and the standard delegate/protocol method works like a charm.